# real sequence $(u_j)_{j\in\Bbb{N}}$ such that $\sum_{j=0}^\infty (2^j+1)\exp(-u_j2^j)<\infty.$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I would like to find a real sequence $(u_j)_{j\in\Bbb{N}}$ such that the series $\sum_{j=1}^\infty u_j$ converges and such that $$\sum_{j=0}^\infty (2^j+1)\exp(-u_j2^j)<\infty.$$

I trind to take $u_j=\frac{1}{4^j}$ but the series $\sum_{j=0}^\infty (2^j+1)\exp(-\frac{1}{2^j})$ diverges. Not sure how can I find such a sequence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$u_j=\frac{1}{j^2}$ fits the bill for example.

Obviously, $\sum_{j=1}^\infty u_j <\infty$, and $\displaystyle 2^j\exp(-\frac{2^j}{j^2})=\exp(j\ln(2)-\frac{2^j}{j^2}) $

Since $\displaystyle \lim_{j\to \infty} 2j\ln(2)-\frac{2^j}{j^2}=-\infty$, $$\exp(j\ln(2)-\frac{2^j}{j^2}) = o\left( \frac{1}{2^j} \right)$$ and convergence follows.

---

Rationale : you want $\sum_{j=1}^\infty u_j$ to converge, so you'd like $u_j$ to be small. At the same time, you want $\sum_{j=0}^\infty (2^j+1)\exp(-u_j2^j)$ to converge, so you want $2^j\exp(-u_j2^j)$ to be small as well. It suffices that $\exp(-u_j2^j)$ goes to $0$ faster than $2^j$ goes to $\infty$, that is to say, $u_j2^j$ goes to infinity very fast. So you don't want $u_j$ to be too small ! Choosing $u_j=\frac{1}{4^j}$ like you did is the worse thing to do.

Comment: Nice, thanks for this