# Study of convergence of a series. Which method best fits?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

Let us consider the following series:
$$\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}(2^{n}+1)e^{\frac{-c^2 n}{2}}\tag{1}$$
where $c$ is a constant.

---

Which method  would fit most so as to *find values of $c$ such that $\mathit{(1)}$ converges*?

Comment: A bit [related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2483992/721644).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint :** $$(2^{n}+1)e^{\frac{-c^2 n}{2}} \sim 2^ne^{\frac{-c^2 n}{2}} = e^{n \left(\ln(2)-\frac{c^2}{2} \right)}$$

which is a geometric series.

Comment: Great! Hence, it will suffice that $\frac{c^2}{2}>\ln(2) \implies c^2>2\ln(2) \implies c< -\sqrt{2\ln(2)}$ or $c>\sqrt{2\ln(2)}$. This way, absolute general term will be lower than $1$ and we are done, since the geometric series will be convergent. Right? @TheSilverDoe

Comment: Correct ! Except that you should not have a $n$ in your formula ;)

Comment: I have edited my comment, now it should be Ok I guess :) Thank you a lot!